# dotnet publish for SingleFile does not include .dylib files

Tags: c#, macos

I am very new with C#, on MacOS Big Sur, I first try the "Hello World" proposed on VisualStudio. I tried to make a single file executable by doing this :

```
$ dotnet publish -r osx.11.0-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.10.2+857e5a733 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  Hello -> /Users/elapouya/projects/csharp/Hello/Hello/bin/Debug/net5.0/osx.11.0-x64/Hello.dll
  Hello -> /Users/elapouya/projects/csharp/Hello/Hello/bin/Debug/net5.0/osx.11.0-x64/publish/
```

and it works fine :

```
$ /Users/elapouya/projects/csharp/Hello/Hello/bin/Debug/net5.0/osx.11.0-x64/publish/Hello
Hello World !!
```

But to be sure it is a standalone executable file with everything in it, I just copied it in another directory an ran it but it failed :

```
$ cd ~/tmp
~/tmp$ cp /Users/elapouya/projects/csharp/Hello/Hello/bin/Debug/net5.0/osx.11.0-x64/publish/Hello .
~/tmp$ ./Hello
Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (Hello.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'runtimepack.Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.osx-x64', version: '5.0.8'
    path: 'libSystem.IO.Compression.Native.dylib'
```

If I look at files generated with the `dotnet publish` I can see :

```
drwxr-xr-x   11 elapouya  staff       352  9 aoû 11:29 .
drwxr-xr-x  192 elapouya  staff      6144  9 aoû 11:03 ..
-rwxr-xr-x    1 elapouya  staff  52687111  9 aoû 11:36 Hello
-rw-r--r--    1 elapouya  staff      9676  9 aoû 11:36 Hello.pdb
-rwxr--r--    1 elapouya  staff    917392 15 jui 21:05 libSystem.IO.Compression.Native.dylib
-rwxr--r--    1 elapouya  staff     70380 15 jui 21:05 libSystem.Native.dylib
-rwxr--r--    1 elapouya  staff     15704 15 jui 21:05 libSystem.Net.Security.Native.dylib
-rwxr--r--    1 elapouya  staff     51588 15 jui 21:05 libSystem.Security.Cryptography.Native.Apple.dylib
-rwxr--r--    1 elapouya  staff    159472 15 jui 21:05 libSystem.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl.dylib
-rwxr--r--    1 elapouya  staff   2624360 15 jui 21:05 libclrjit.dylib
-rwxr--r--    1 elapouya  staff   6958844 15 jui 21:07 libcoreclr.dylib
```

There are many `.dylib` here, including the one from the error that occured when the program was executed in `~/tmp`.

The `.csproj` is :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>osx.11.0-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

and `dotnet --info` :

```
DK .NET (reflétant tous les fichiers global.json) :
 Version:   5.0.302
 Commit:    c005824e35

Environnement d'exécution :
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  11.0
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.11.0-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.302/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.8
  Commit:  35964c9215

.NET SDKs installed:
  3.1.411 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  5.0.302 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.17 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.8 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.17 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.8 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

What should I do to have a single file executable that can be run anywhere on any osx 11.0 ?

Comment: Did you tried to explicitly set --self-contained to true? Looks like it should be true by default, but...

Comment: There is already a `<SelfContained>true</SelfContained>` in the .csproj

Comment: Try specify [IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file#including-native-libraries)

Comment: @Magnetron : It works with your flag : thank you

Answer (score 1):

Now it works : The final `.csproj` to have an all-in-one executable file with a minimum size is :

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>true</IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>
    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
    <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```